# ReactiveMongo query failing to paginate

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

Having some issues getting ReactiveMongo `0.11` to paginate my query. The behavior is that it is returning *all* results, instead of the page-by-page results.

Here's my query:

```
def listConvos(userId: String, page: Int, pageSize: Int) = {
val query = BSONDocument("userId" -> userId)
val sort = BSONDocument("lastActivity" -> -1)
val skipN = (page-1) * pageSize
val queryOptions = new QueryOpts(skipN = skipN, batchSizeN = pageSize, flagsN = 0)

collection.find(query).options(queryOptions).sort(sort).cursor[ConvoDesc](ReadPreference.primaryPreferred).collect[List]()
```

Note that pagination starts at `1`. Using the IntelliJ debugger, the values for the variables above are:

```
userId = "29aosidfj43903p"
query = BSONDocument(<non-empty>)
sort = BSONDocument(<non-empty>)
queryOptions = QueryOpts(10,10,0)
page = 2
pageSize = 10
```

I can also confirm I've set a compound index on the `userId` and `lastActivity` fields. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please indicate the versions you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to also include the page size in the `collect` method like so:

```
collection.find(query).options(queryOptions).sort(sort).cursor[ConvoDesc](ReadPreference.primaryPreferred).collect[List](pageSize)
```